# Formatting a numeric field to fixed length in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report where a numeric field needs to be a fixed length with a decimal and needs to not round up or down. I changed it to a text field but now when I run the report and I forget to change the options in crystal for a number field to show ####.## it rounds to nearest dollar amount and drops the cents. How can I fix it so I won't have to remember to change the options?

Comment: Can you show example...unable to understand

Comment: sure.. here is what I have first.formula "totext({Dollar.amountfield}, "000000000.00")" second.formula "left({first.formula},9)&right({first.formula),2) because in the first formula the numeric field is being changed to text it will not keep the cents if I have the options in my crystal set to no decimal points.  The final result for that dollar amount needs to be fixed.

Comment: why are you using `totext({Dollar.amountfield}, "000000000.00")`.. I don't see any use of `"000000000.00"` in totext function... can you explain the use also does your amount field have decimals that will represent cents? and are you adding zeros to leading or trailing to fix the lenght and if your amount has more characters than you expected are you handling in this function?

Comment: Yes this field needs to be a fixed length field.  I inherited this file so I'm not exactly sure of the logic behind it but I believe it was to make it a fixed length field so if the dollar amount will have leading zeros. the amounts can have cents values and I don't want my report to round up or down hence having to change the number field in the options before running this report.  the amount shouldn't have more than what's allotted.

Answer (score 0):

An example may be helpful -

If the field is numeric, or decimal, you can right click the field, select "format field", click Customize, Number, and select the rounding and decimal logic. [image]

if you don't have enough decimal places allowed (say, zero decimals) then make sure the rounding is not set to "1" - that would cause the number to round up. if the rounding is less than or equal to the decimal places, it should just 'truncate' and not round.

Comment: thank you for replying :)  The problem I am running into is that I have to take the field and change it to a text field so I can make it a certain fixed length.  is there a way to format the field then use that formatted field in my formula so it will hold the decimal places?

Comment: Absolutely - take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169227/crystal-report-issue-with-int-to-string-conversion - If you create a formula to convert the numeric field totext, you can specify how many decimal places to use. `ToText(x, y, z, w) x=The number to convert to texty=The number of decimal places to include in result (optional). The value will be rounded to that decimal place.`